# how to get quality cropped bitmap when straighten applied for imageview in android

Tags: android, bitmap, rotation, crop

I think it should be duplicate but i didn't get any solution for this question. and my question is :

I am developing an application which is having features like Crop with aspect ratios and crop with Rotation and Straightening. for that I'm using [this](https://github.com/rameshkec85/AndroidCropMoveScaleImage) library. Features crop,rotation and straighten working fine but my question is after calling Crop function for straightening image then result not having good quality.  how do i overcome this issue?

here is the code what i have used for cropping :

```
private Bitmap getCurrentDisplayedImage() {
Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(mImageView.getWidth(), mImageView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(result);
mImageView.draw(c);
return result;}

// Get the scale factor between the actual Bitmap dimensions and the
// displayed dimensions for width.
float actualImageWidth = mCurrentDisplayedBitmap.getWidth();
float displayedImageWidth = displayedImageRect.width();
float scaleFactorWidth = actualImageWidth / displayedImageWidth;

// Get the scale factor between the actual Bitmap dimensions and the
// displayed dimensions for height.
float actualImageHeight = mCurrentDisplayedBitmap.getHeight();
float displayedImageHeight = displayedImageRect.height();
float scaleFactorHeight = actualImageHeight / displayedImageHeight;

// Get crop window position relative to the displayed image.
float cropWindowX = Edge.LEFT.getCoordinate() - displayedImageRect.left;
float cropWindowY = Edge.TOP.getCoordinate() - displayedImageRect.top;
float cropWindowWidth = Edge.getWidth();
float cropWindowHeight = Edge.getHeight();

// Scale the crop window position to the actual size of the Bitmap.
float actualCropX = cropWindowX * scaleFactorWidth;
float actualCropY = cropWindowY * scaleFactorHeight;
float actualCropWidth = cropWindowWidth * scaleFactorWidth;
float actualCropHeight = cropWindowHeight * scaleFactorHeight;

// Crop the subset from the original Bitmap.
Bitmap croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mCurrentDisplayedBitmap, (int) actualCropX, (int) actualCropY, (int) actualCropWidth, (int) actualCropHeight);
return croppedBitmap;}
```

i googled and i tried so many ways but didn't find any better solution.

if anyone have idea please help me.

Thanks in Adavance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

`Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int xStart, int yStart, int xSize, int ySize, Matrix matrix, boolean render)`
and set render to true.  You can also optionally apply a matrix which can handle rotations and resizing with this method like so:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postScale(float xScale, float yScale);
matrix.postRotate(int degrees);
```

Otherwise simply set Matrix to null.

Note: the Matrix rotate method rotates clockwise with positive values and counterclockwise for negative values.

Comment: thanks for reply.. actually "createScaledBitmap" don't have six parameters. it have only four parameters only i tried with four parameters  but not getting good quality.

Comment: that's what I get for trying to respond from memory I guess.  Just use Bitmap.createBitmap.  I'll update the post to show it.  If you are still having trouble you probably need to use a higher resolution picture.  There are several drawing programs that can do this.  I recomend Krita.

Comment: i tried like this also but when i resize low resolution image to normal resolution image then result not having quality.

Comment: i think problem is not in Bitmap creation, it is in cropping. will you check on that? i'm also look on that..

Comment: the four elements after the bitmap argument can be used to crop the image, but it sounds as if your problem is the resolution of the starting image.  It can only be expanded so much without beginning to look pixelated.  Setting the final argument in createBitmap to true can help some of this but it sounds as if you need to get a good image creation program.  As I said I recommend Krita.  It is free, yet very powerful.  Many will see the shear amount of options available to be daunting but if you keep playing with it you'll see there's little you can't do with it.